# How to intercept requests in ASP.NET 5 without IHttpModule?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am looking to implement an interceptor, as far as my research, `IHttpModule` is outdated.

Is there an alternative with ASP.NET 5?

Same for event handling.

Comment: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/269/asp-net-5-middleware-or-where-has-my-httpmodule-gone

Comment: [Middleware](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/269/asp-net-5-middleware-or-where-has-my-httpmodule-gone).

Comment: If mvc (in addition to middleware, ihttphandler), implement custom ActionFilterAttribute (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx), but assuming since you mention event handling probably not MVC.

Comment: As replied by @Abhitalks that article covers changes in ASP.NET 5 & how to intercept request...

Comment: @DarthVader - Instead of downvoting with an offensive comment, you can comment with what's not working. I'm talking about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688662/how-to-override-default-unhandled-exception-output-in-owin/28689030#28689030).